# Change each letter of a word in a label as the user types it. Can I do it using JS or CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was asked to create a credit card that has its informations filled as the user types it, so for example, the card number is pre-defined as "#### #### #### ####" and when the user types the card number in another input like "542" it changes the text to "542# #### #### ####". It's also supposed to have like a little animation of pushing the "#" upwards as the new number comes out.

Comment: Yes it is possible, but you have to attempt it yourself first. No one here will code that from scratch for you.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended as a free do-it-for-you completion device. Instead, illustrate a good faith effort on your behalf by sharing an attempt at solving the problem, along with a short explanation as to why the attempt doesn’t meet your requirements. (Please also consider the academic integrity implications of posting coursework for completion by the community on your behalf without at the very least making an attempt at completion.) See also: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: man, i've searching about it for the second day now. I'm already able to pass what's written on the input for the label, but I can't find anything about keeping the last word and adding an animation on it.

Comment: You still need to provide us with what you've tried: what works, what doesn't, where you've gotten stuck, etc.. If you don't, we can only guess.